# Obtener el valor de un checkbox y mostrarlo en input text js o jquery

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia como podria obtener el valor un checkbox y posteriormente mostralo en un input text.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addproduct" action="index.php?view=addproduct" role="form">


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fiscal</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-check">
               <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2" name="fiscal" id="fiscal">
                    Fiscal
                </label>  
          </div>

      <input type="text" name="id_fiscal" class="form-control" id="id_fiscal">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Existencias Fiscal:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="fiscal" class="form-control" id="fiscal" placeholder="Existencias Fiscales">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nacional</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-check">
               <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="nacional" id="nacional">
                    Nacional
                </label>  
          </div>

      <input type="text" name="id_nacional" class="form-control" id="id_nacional">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Existencias Nacional:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="nacional" class="form-control" id="nacional" placeholder="Existencias Nacionales">
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Producto</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Tengo 2 checkbook, y requiero cuando este activado o selecionado me muestra el valor en mi input text de id_fiscal (2)  e id_nacional (1).

Comment: te recomiendo no usar el mismo `id` para más de un elemento porque luego eso crea conflictos en el DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción sería escuchar al evento `change` del *checkbox* para luego validar cuando esté *checkeado* y añadir el *value* al *Text* , teniendo en consideración No repetir el Id para más de un elemento , recuerde **`es un Identificador único`**

Para el ejemplo quité los elementos con id repetidos

```js
$(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]' ,function(e) {
    if(this.id=="fiscal") {
        if(this.checked) $('#id_fiscal').val(this.value);
        else $('#id_fiscal').val("");
    }
    if(this.id=="nacional") {
        if(this.checked) $('#id_nacional').val(this.value);
        else $('#id_nacional').val("");
    }
});

/* Escuchando por Separado*/
/* 
$(document).on('change','#fiscal' ,function(e) {
    if(this.checked) $('#id_fiscal').val(this.value);
    else $('#id_fiscal').val("");
});

$(document).on('change','#nacional' ,function(e) {
    if(this.checked) $('#id_nacional').val(this.value);
    else $('#id_nacional').val("");
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fiscal</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-check">
               <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2" name="fiscal" id="fiscal">
                    Fiscal
                </label>  
          </div>
      <input type="text" name="id_fiscal" class="form-control" id="id_fiscal">
    </div>
    
<label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nacional</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-check">
               <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="nacional" id="nacional">
                    Nacional
                </label>  
          </div>

      <input type="text" name="id_nacional" class="form-control" id="id_nacional">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es javascript puro:

```
function uncheck(){
checkbox2.onclick = function(){
if(document.getElementById("vehiculo").checked==true){
        document.getElementById("vehiculo").value=55;
        document.getElementById("costo").value=document.getElementById("vehiculo").value;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("costo").value="";
    }
if(document.getElementById("moto").checked==true){
        document.getElementById("moto").value=35;
        document.getElementById("costo").value=document.getElementById("moto").value;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("costo").value="";
    }
}
}
```